# how can i display the correct format of my article that made in WYSIWYG editor using vue js and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, wysiwyg

I want to display my customized article from WYSIWYG editor using Vue.js.

In Laravel I just do `{!! $article->content !!}` to show whole content please help me how to display it using Vue.js `{{article.content}}`

Comment: share your vuejs snippet ?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to use `v-html` directive to display html in vuejs

```
<div v-html="article.content"></div>
```

[Doc link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

Comment: i already tried it but it's still not working because i'm using tui editor https://github.com/nhn/tui.editor    please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Use `v-html` in your vue component.

```
<p v-html="article.content"></p>
```

Comment: its not working because i'm using tui-editor    link here https://github.com/nhn/tui.editor

Comment: Try to use triple curly braces. `{{{ variable }}}` . I hope it helps. Good Luck.